# Many files in android project files

Tags: java, android

in android project files it show many file than the original.how to return previous which has the main and resource

[image]

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the files that are shown. They are exactly the same files that are in any Android Project. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Ask your question more precise. What are you thinking is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **Project Files**. Then set as **Android**.

Comment: Okay, Then you should vote or accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Click on **Project Files**.
It'll open a menu, choose **Android**.

That is all.